# WPF TemplateBinding does not work for every property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created custom control, but `TemplateBinding` does not work for every property?
Template Binding does start working if I use dummy Converter that just forwards original values.
Simplified example that has the same issue:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ElipticProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ElipticProgressBar}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <converters:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!--BarColor works always-->
                    <!--BarTickness works-->
                    <Label Background="{TemplateBinding BarColor}" Content="{TemplateBinding BarTickness}"/>
                    <!--BarTickness does not works-->
                    <TextBlock Background="{TemplateBinding BarColor}" Text="{TemplateBinding BarTickness}"/>
                    <!--BarTickness works-->
                    <TextBlock Background="{TemplateBinding BarColor}" Text="{Binding BarTickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <!--BarTickness works-->
                    <TextBlock Background="{TemplateBinding BarColor}" Text="{TemplateBinding BarTickness, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

back code:

```
public class ElipticProgressBar : Control
{
    static ElipticProgressBar()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ElipticProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ElipticProgressBar)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarTicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BarTickness", typeof(int), typeof(ElipticProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int BarTickness
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(BarTicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarTicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BarColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ElipticProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    public Brush BarColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BarColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
controls:ElipticProgressBar BarTickness="30" BarColor="Orange"
```

DebugConverter:

```
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension) that a `{TemplateBinding}` is

> an optimized form of a Binding for template scenarios, analogous to a Binding constructed with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`

with some limitations - most importantly that **it works only within the visual tree!**

---

What that means for your specific case: while you cannot use

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding BarTickness}" />
```

you can (and have to) use

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BarTickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

because `TextBlock.Text` property is of type `string` while the `BarTickness` is not.

`{TemplateBinding}` does not do that kind of converting; that's why you need to use the more generic `{Binding}` or a converter, whose both methods

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}
```

both convert the actual value to an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

`{TemplateBinding}` is an optimized version of a binding that has some limitations.

In this case you need to change the type of the `BarThickness` property to `string` to be able to bind it directly to the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` using a `{TemplateBinding}`.